# Сократить запрос - селект и апдейт на апдейт

Tags: mysql, update, insert

Встала задачка - записывать в базу бронирование мест в кафе, с отображением в виде диаграммы. При этом нельзя бронировать одно место на несколько человек)))
Имею две таблицы, все поля int:
table1 - id, place, status (3000 строк, place числовой ряд от 1 до 3000)
table2 - id, start, stop (заявки от клиентов на места от start до stop, например:
id=1, start=200, stop=240  (бронь на места с 200 по 240)
id=2, start=45, stop=55  (бронь на места с 45 по 55)
и т.д.

Получаю две переменные из скрипта:  $start, $stop

Придумал алгоритм в 4 шага и 2 запроса:

1. Пробегаю по table1 с условием что номера мест попадают в интервал, пришедший от клиента и при этом статус = 0, т.е. свободно, получаю count
2. Сравниваю полученный count c количеством заказываемых мест, т.е. $start-$stop
3. Если count равен $delta, то обновляю в table1 поле status=1 для указанных мест и
4. В table2 вставляю новую строку с параметрами брони

Если count НЕ равен $delta, то сообщаю клиенту что необходимый интервал занят.

Вся кутерьма сугубо из-за того, чтобы сообщить клиенту что он не прав)))
И вот вопрос - как сократить кол-во запросов в базу?
И второй вопрос - между п.1 и п.3 будет какой-то временной интервал, т.е. возможно наложение, п.2 дает добро и в это время еще один запрос от клиента, пишу две строки в table2 c одинаковыми параметрами??

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (place >= $start AND place < $stop) AND status=0  

if ($count == $delta) {  blabla }  

UPDATE table1 SET status=1 WHERE (place >= $start AND place < $stop) 

INSERT INTO table2 (start,stop) VALUES ($start,$stop)
```

Comment: А что такое эта таблица1 - список мест со статусами ? И почему к вас нигде не фигурируют никакие даты. На какое число-время бронь, сколько она длится будет и т.п. Это я все к тому, что по хорошему можно было бы обойтись одной таблицей и всю бронь выполнять за одну операцию, включающую в себя заодно и проверки на занятость. И тогда ни о каких наложениях и речи не будет. Но для такой таблицы точно понадобятся даты. И понимание как эти даты должны работать ...

Comment: Таблица table1 - просто числовой ряд, т.е. 3000 строк, заполненных изначально (поле place заполнено от 1 до 3000) и далее апдейтится только поле статус. Даты не фигурируют, так как на каждый утро table1 снова в исходном состоянии (статусы в каждой строке = 0), суть не в бронировании на месяц вперед, сегодня бронируем места на  завтрашний день, завтра клиенты пришли и сели согласно купленным так сказать билетам, такое типа конвейерное кафе)). На какое время тоже не нужно - место за клиентом бронируется на весь день. такие вот нюансы.

Comment: с другой стороны, сейчас поиск свободного места идет максимально быстро, select с банальными условиями без join. если все делать в одной таблице, то наверное будут join-ы и тд, скорость будет плакать, не?

Comment: сначала делается структура в "нормальной форме", потом, для оптимизации она денормализуется. Если по каким то причинам поиск по одному дню в таблице броней, что бы найти свободные - долгий (в чем я сильно сомневаюсь, при наличии индекса на колонку с датой) то да, делается таблица со статусами и статус меняется триггером на insert в таблицу броней, при ошибке он автоматом все откатывает. Правда остается узкое место со сбросом статусов в 0. В БД периодические задачи не очень хороши, вдруг света не будет и сервер будет offline в то время когда должна проходить задача сброса ...

Comment: т.е. все-таки триггер? если обработать мой заглавный вопрос согласно теории лаконичности)), то в идеале  хотел услышать вариант, как вставить 1 строку (где select) и 2 строку (где проверка на равенство) в 3 строку внутрь UPDATE. 4 строка уже не так критична в плане ошибки, вернее, там её не будет в принципе, если делать туда запись после правильного UPDATE в 1-й таблице. Т.е. подобно похожей задаче с уникальным полем, когда если есть строка то апдейт, если нет  то вставить, в МОЕМ случае - если есть равенство то апдейт, если нет - то отмена апдейта.

Comment: Ну я привык когда БД _гарантирует_ свою непротиворечивость вне зависимости от любых внешних факторов, включая возможные ошибки в клиентском приложении. Поэтому и триггер. Вы конечно можете при соединении с БД выключить автокоммит, сделать таблицы innoDB и давать commit только после того как выполнили все операции. Кстати, а почему `select *` и потом некий $count ? вы решили записи в клиентском приложении пересчитывать ? вот этим вы точно всю производительность убьете. `select count(*)` стоит использовать ... В общем я сейчас напишу ответ как должно быть, а вы сами решайте :)

Comment: угу, спс. насчет count - я ж юзаю PDO (код упростил для понимания). и в PDO счетчик вроде как так можно получить - SELECT * FROM blabla...; $count = (int)$sth->rowCount();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит немного пересмотреть структуру базы, так, что бы она в принципе не позволяла записать в себя не полную информацию.

В Table1 делаем единственную колонку place и заполняем ее номерами существующих мест. Она нам потребуется для запросов.

Table2 - т.е. сами брони кроме диапазона мест добавляем колонку с датой (`dt`) на которую эта бронь. Обязательно создаете уникальный индекс из колонок `dt, start` (именно в таком порядке).

Получение списка свободных мест:

```
select place
  from Table1 T1
  left join Table2 T2
    on T2.dt=curdate() and T1.place between T2.start and T2.stop
 where T2.dt is NULL
```

Вместо `curdate()` тут и далее можете подставить любую дату на которую хотите посмотреть места.

Далее клиентское приложение перед началом брони проверяет доступны ли все места (только что бы сообщить в интерфейсе, в момент брони все равно будет еще одна проверка).

```
select count(*)
  from Table2
 where dt=curdate()
   and stop>=$start and start<=$stop
```

Если запрос вернул не 0 - то есть занятые места в выбранном диапазоне.

И наконец, само бронирование:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (dt,start,stop)
 select curdate(), $start, $stop
  where not exists(
     select 1 from Table2
      where dt=curdate()
        and stop>=$start and start<=$stop
  )
```

После запроса клиентское приложение должно проверить количество обработанных записей (например с помощью [PDO::RowCount()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php), если у вас PHP. в любом языке есть подобные функции при работе с БД). Если количество не равно 1 - значит на момент вставки места уже были заняты, чем и огорчаем клиента.

Comment: хм, отлично! щас по времени потестирую. уникальный индекс нужен только для первых двух запросв из вашего ответа или он будет помогать еще и при третьем запросе (там где INSERT)?? все-таки если мне не нужна curdate, то нужен ли будет уник индекс по одному полу start?

Comment: @СергейВ. Индекс любому поиску помогать будет. но я не понимаю как вы без даты обойдетесь. утром на день бронируют и на следующий день таблица очищается и начинаем с чистого листа.

Comment: ну в вашем варианте может и нужна, так изначально первая таблица была нужна только для быстрого поиска. а сами бронирования с датами так или иначе есть в системе, в других таблицах, с привязкой по id от таблицы2 . возможно ваш вариант вообще все таблицы в одну сведет. я просто где-то вычитал что писать в таблицу, к которой сделан подзапрос - нельзя.

Comment: Да, проверил, все работает четко на 1млн строк, тысячные доли секунды! Рекомендую всем http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike как очень умного коллегу!

Comment: интересно, а как строить логику, а если нужно будет сохранять заказы, в которых клиент не будет указывать предпочтительное место, а давать ему сразу первое свободное в ряду?

Comment: в вашем первом запросе идет сравнение каждого с каждым, подобное я пробовал, время выполнения безумное получается, навряд ли получится использовать для поиска первого свободного

Comment: а если при сохранении заказа делать подряд два запроса - insert + update, из которых второй - в table1 - обновит поле статус у тех мест, которые придут из первого insert (да, все таки там его оставить, это поле status). тогда поиск первого свободного будет очень быстрым (найти в table строку со статусом 0 и сортировка по id) и в то же время не будет коллизии, ведь ваш этот супер вариант не даст в любом случае записать дубликат (если например по времени два клиенты одновременно начнут тыкать кнопочки)??

Comment: да может и недолго будет выполняться, я просто всегда пробую на миллионной таблице)) в первой 1млн строк во второй было 5000 строк, запрос выполнялся 370 сек!)) типа такого запроса (тут поиск двух свободных мест): select x
from table1 (тут 1млн строк где перечислены все комбинации)
left join table2 (тут 5000 строк с заказами)
on x <= X2-1 and
   x+2 >= X1
where x+2<1000 
and id is null
order by x;

Comment: а вообще для таких операции как в вашем третьем варианте (когда само  бронирование) что лучше InnoDb или MyISAM?

Comment: @СергейВ. Кстати, если поиск первых свободных мест нужен, можете отдельный вопрос сформулировать и задать. Только обязательно укажите, что у вас все таки с датами происходит, без них кажется что в таблице всего максимум 3к записей. Я как и говорил вижу 2 пути, один с переменными, другой - поиск занятых интервалов после которых достаточно места (с использованием только Table2), но надо пробовать ... А коменты тут, не относящиеся к основной теме этого вопроса надо чистить, я сейчас как раз это начну ...

Comment: создал http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568258/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-mysql