# Найти в ряду крайнюю слева незанятую ячейку запросом MySQL

Tags: mysql, update, insert

По совету участника вынес подвопрос в отдельную тему.
Встала задачка - записывать в базу бронирование мест в кафе, с отображением в виде диаграммы. При этом нельзя бронировать одно место на несколько человек)))
Имею две таблицы, все поля int:

`table1`- `id`, `place`, `status` (3000 строк, place числовой ряд от 1 до 3000)
`table2` - `id`, `start`, `stop` (заявки от клиентов на места),

например:

id=1, start=200, stop=240 (бронь на места с 200 по 240) id=2, start=45, stop=55 (бронь на места с 45 по 55) и т.д.

В таблице `table2` бронирование (вставка строки) на группы мест осуществляется через другой запрос.

Вопрос1 - как создавать новое бронирование (в table2) на ближайшее к началу свободное место или на несколько ближайших к началу мест?

Предварительно решаю так (тут проблема в п.2 и п.3):

1. При новом бронировании на группу мест пишу в table2 (запрос сам ищет свободные ГРУППЫ мест с учетом выбранных клиентом)
2. Затем делаю UPDATE в table1 - всем строкам, у которых place попадает в диапазон start-stop обновляю status =1
3. Если надо забронировать одно крайнее слева свободное место, то делаю `UPDATE` в table1 через `UPDATE table1 SET status=1 WHERE status=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` и затем это забронированое место вставляю в table2 как новое бронирование.

Налицо избыточное хранение и наверное возможны коллизии при массированном бронировании... Как тут можно сделать красивый запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант по таблице статусов (совершенно не понимаю зачем они вообще нужны) `@need` - требуемое количество мест:

```
insert into table2(start, stop)
 select min(place)-@need+1,min(place)
   from (
     select @num:=if(place=@lp+1,@num+1,1) num,@lp:=place as place
       from table1, (select @lp:=0, @num:=0, @need:=6) A
      where status=0
      order by place
   ) X
  where num=@need
```

В данном случае мы берем все незанятые записи и нумеруем порядковыми номерами неразрывные участки, т.е. сразу после разрыва нумерации (т.е. занятости какого то места) мы начинаем нумеровать записи с 1. И берем минимальную запись у которой порядковый номер равен требуемому количеству мест. Все записи непосредственно *до* нее заведомо свободны.

При отсутствии статуса в первой таблице (только список всех мест) в верхнюю часть запроса можно добавить left join с таблицей броней для получения свободных мест.

Вариант 2, без использования таблицы статусов как таковой, ориентируемся только на существующие записи брони. В запросе добавляется специальная запись с местом 0, что бы от нее можно было вести отсчет. При желании такую запись можно навсегда положить в таблицу броней, что бы не делать в запросе union, который может мешать оптимизатору. Заменить "5" на количество требуемых мест (3000 - максимальный номер места):

```
insert into table2(start, stop)
select A.stop+1, A.stop+1+5
  from (
    select 0 as start, 0 as stop
    union all
    select start, stop from table2
     where stop<3000-5
  ) A
 where not exists(
   select 1 from table2 B
    where B.start>A.start and B.start<A.stop+1+5
   )
 order by A.start
 limit 1
```

Тут мы ищем первую запись броней (включая виртуальную 0), после которой можно положить требуемый блок мест.
Если поле id автоинкремент то после вставки можно получить его функцией `last_insert_id()` и использовать для обновления статуса в первой таблице.

**UPD** Если запись 0,0 уже будет в таблице то запрос упростится:

```
insert into table2(start, stop)
select A.stop+1, A.stop+1+5
  from table2 A
 where A.stop<3000-5
   and not exists(
   select 1 from table2 B
    where B.start>A.start and B.start<A.stop+1+5
   )
 order by A.start
 limit 1
```

Comment: По Варианту 2: если запись с местом 0 создам в таблице, что можно выкинуть из запроса?

Comment: @СергейВ. Написал в ответе

Comment: ок, отличное решение! и еще - попробовал для удобства вывести визуально, 3000 элементов в строку явно не айс)) интересно, если отображать в виде матрицы, например, 50х60, как мне модифицировать код, чтобы получать не start и stop, а смещение по горизонтали и по вертикали ,т.е. уже 4 переменных: start1 start2 stop2 stop2?

Comment: @СергейВ. Мне кажется матрицу уже проще на клиенте рисовать. Если у вас места фактически идут подряд а вы их прямоугольником отображаете, то у вас первый и последний ряды области могут быть не полными. т.е. прямоугольник не ровный и двумя парами координат не описывается. А если у вас зал физически имеет некую геометрию, то это надо отражать в структуре БД что бы его адекватно отображать

Comment: места надо занимать по порядку, т.е. подряд, верно. а геометрия как раз прямоугольник. что имеется ввиду под структурой БД? поля я создал для всех 4 параметров, вывод тоже набросал, цикл же простейший, только теперь не от 0 до 3000, а  от 0 до 60 горизонт и от 0 до 50 вертикаль. теперь осталось туда их вписывать...)) я имел ввиду что как запросом в БД также определять пустые места и занимать их через INSERT.

Comment: @СергейВ. предположим у вас запрашивают 3 места, подряд. но на ряду свободно одно последнее место и следующие за ним 2 места - это уже в начале следующего ряда. Получающаяся фигура ну никак не прямоугольник и четырьмя координатами описать его невозможно. Или вы координаты начала поставите ряд 1 место 60 и координаты 2 ряд 2 место 2. Но тогда любые номера мест из линейной системы только с номером места легко арифметическим выражением переводятся в ряд и место, тупо делением на 60 с остатком

Comment: это тоже верно. я еще вот что имел ввиду - физически места расположены именно как матрица - 60х50, т.е. логичнее на ОДИН заказа давать кучно, а не вразброс. понятно что это лишняя работа по формированию кода, но в плане повышения лояльности клиента лучше не придумать. и.е. по сути эта функция должна называться: забронировать :(например) мест ближайшие свободные слева направо и сверху вниз но кучкой (прямоугольником в данном случае)!

Comment: @СергейВ. Тогда посмотрите это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564888/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql/564928#564928

Comment: не получилось соединить ваш и тот запросы