# Посчитать максимальное количество значений подряд

Tags: mysql

Есть столбец, в котором идут положительные и отрицательные значения. Нужно посчитать максимальное количество ПОДРЯД. Т.е. к примеру: 22, 33, 56, -85, -45, 68 - здесь получается 3 подряд положительных и 2 подряд отрицательных. Помогите составить запрос SQL

Comment: А что такое "подряд" ? видимо есть еще какая то колонка с порядком сортировки записей ?

Comment: И вот буквально вчера был вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568258/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-mysql/568411#568411  посмотрите там в ответе подзапрос в первом примере, там как раз одинаковые значения подряд нумеруются ...

Comment: Подряд имел ввиду сортировку по колонке даты и колонке времени

Answer (score 2):

С помощью функции `sign()` получаем знак чисел и сравниваем со знаком из предыдущей строки. Нумеруем записи подряд пока знак сохраняется. Максимальные порядковые номера для каждого знака и есть искомое:

```
select S, max(num)
  from (
   select @num:=if(sign(VAL)=@lp,@num+1,1) num,@lp:=sign(VAL) S
     from table1, (select @lp:=0, @num:=0) A
    order by ORDER_COLUMN
  ) A
  group by S
```