# Как в запросе select (mysql) можно посчитать количество последних значений, равных между собой, и идущих непрерывно?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, select

Как в запросе select (mysql) можно посчитать количество последних значений, равных между собой, и идущих непрерывно?

Вот пример таблицы: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
http://c2n.me/3Gqmp8u

В данном случае, запрос должен вернуть 2.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568737/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(x.num) - MIN(x.num) result
FROM (
     SELECT MAX(id_chat_message) num, is_readed
     FROM `table`
     GROUP BY is_readed
     ) x
```

Если в значениях id_chat_message имеются "дырки", то, например,

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE id_chat_message > (
                        SELECT MIN(x.num)
                        FROM (
                             SELECT MAX(id_chat_message) num, is_readed
                             FROM `table`
                             GROUP BY is_readed
                             ) x
                        )
```

При любом количестве возможных значений статуса и наличии хотя бы 2 записей с разными статусами вроде должен дать верный результат такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
WHERE id_chat_message > (               
                        SELECT MAX(id_chat_message)
                        FROM `table`
                        GROUP BY is_readed
                        ORDER BY 1 DESC 
                        LIMIT 2,1
                        )
```

Comment: Спасибо. Для данного примера задача решена, но если в столбце is_readed будет набор не только из 1 и 0, то не сработает.

Comment: Да, гораздо проще получится запрос с использованием переменной - но он плох тем, что это будет фуллскан таблицы.