# Помогите составить запрос на MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Таблица вида:

```
id___user_id___lender_id___status
1    1         2           P
2    1         3           P
3    1         4           P
4    1         5           P
5    1         6           P
6    1         7           S
7    1         6           P
8    2         1           P
9    2         3           P
10   2         1           S
```

Необходимо вывести user_id, если у него 5+ неудачных статусов подряд ( status != "S" ) с 4+ разными lender_id.

Результат данного запроса: user_id = 1

Comment: А что такое "подряд" ? в SQL не определено какая запись первая, а какая идет за ней, до тех пор пока в запросе не определена сортировка. И что вы сами пробовали сделать для решения вашей задачи ? И как может быть 3 неудачных статуса с 4 разными lender, вы уж определитесь сколько записей должно быть, не менее 3 или не менее 4

Comment: @Mike если следующая запись имеет статус S тогда в условие выборки не входит, смотрим дальше и считаем заново количество статус не равные S. То что есть у меня, пока не работает и совсем мало для показа. Да есть опечатка, сейчас исправлю

Comment: А что такое "следующая запись", как понять, что какая то запись следующая, а не предыдущая ? Вообще в MySQL для обработки подряд идущих записей удобно использовать переменные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568737/

Comment: @Mike да, наверно еще хранимые процедуры надо будет использовать

Comment: ну хранимые то точно не нужны. с чего бы это. практически все что угодно можно получить одним запросом без процедур

Comment: Вот меня больше всего волнует как проверить "подряд" ли они идут

Comment: Вы ссылку, что я дал, посмотрели ? там прекрасно видно, как в переменной запоминать значения, которые были в предыдущей (с учетом заданной сортировки) строке. А на ваш вопрос ответить невозможно, до тех пор пока вы не скажете в каком порядке идут записи

Comment: @Mike записи идут по возрастанию, т.е. нужно смотреть по id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На классическом SQL: для всех записей со статусом не S подбираем такие записи у которых user_id совпадает, id больше или равен (т.е. эта же запись), а status то же не S и при этом не существует записей со статусом S у которых user совпадает а id между двумя вышеописанными. После чего записи группируем по id из первой таблицы (все записи идущие без разрывов будут с одним id), считаем и проверяем нужные количества. При этом user_id может дублироваться, если у него окажется несколько участков подходящих под условия, поэтому применяем distinct.

```
select distinct A.user_id
  from Table1 A
  join Table1 B
    on B.user_id=A.user_id and B.id>=A.id and B.status!='S'
   and not exists(select 1 from Table1 C
                   where C.user_id=A.user_id and C.status='S'
                     and C.id>A.id and C.id<B.id
                 )
 where A.status!='S'
 group by A.id, A.user_id
 having count(1)>=5 and count(distinct B.lender_id)>=4
```

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a041d8/2)

С помощью переменных, только для MySQL, работать должен значительно быстрее первого так как за один проход таблицы. Тут мы вводим переменную rank которую увеличиваем на 1 всякий раз когда встречаем запись со статусом S. Таким образом с одинаковым rank может быть только одна запись со статусом S и несколько записей идущие непосредственно за ней с другими статусами. Записи S отбрасываем, считаем оставшиеся записи с одинаковыми rank.

```
select distinct user_id
  from (
   select user_id, lender_id, status, @rank:=@rank+(status='S') rank
     from Table1 T, (select @rank:=0) i
    order by user_id, id
  ) X
 where status!='S'
 group by user_id, rank
 having count(1)>=5 and count(distinct lender_id)>=4
```

[Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a041d8/3)

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: @Barlukov Я еще вариант с переменной сделал, покороче получился ;)

Comment: Да, тут заметно лучше скорость, ты просто лучший!